# JPA Entity access different schema

Tags: jpa, persistence

I'm working on a web application and one of its functionality would allow the user to switch between database schemas from a drop down select option. Is there anyway to change default schema programmatically? I'm using JPA.

Comment: what do you mean default ? after or before creating the EMF ?

Comment: @Neil I have a orm.xml file which contains the default schema  and I want to somehow change that or other ways to switch between schemas dynamically .

Comment: You create an EMF with a persistence unit name, and can also pass a set of optional properties. So put the schema in the optional props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of Hibernate provide [multi tenancy support](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) which allows changing the schema programaticaly

Comment: Could you switch at runtime. I know how to change it programmatically but I couldn't find a way to switch between schemas at runtime. For example, I have a GUI that allows user to select  between schema A, B, C which then set the selected schema to the entity object. Everything happens after Entity Manager is injected in Session Bean